# the meaning of the sentence quoted from The Scarlet Letter

Tags: paraphrasing

Could you paraphrase this sentence in an easy style? 
: " The Scarlet letter,"he states flatly in a one-sentence paragraph, "had not done its office." 
Is there anything to do with office?

Comment: Have you looked up the word **office** in a couple of dictionaries to find out the various meanings the word has?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/office?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld See 4 a)

Answer (score 1):

As you guess, in this case "office" has nothing to do with any physical structure or location.  This actually more closely related to the original meaning of the word.

> [**office**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/office) (n):  mid-13c., "a post, an employment to which certain duties are attached," from Anglo-French and Old French *ofice* "place or function; divine service" (12c. in Old French) or directly from Latin *officium* "service, kindness, favor; official duty, function, business; ceremonial observance"

You can still find this definition in many modern dictionaries, although this use today feels a little *archaic* or at least *formal*.  Over time, "office" has come to refer more to the *place* where one performs official duties, than the duties themselves.

Still, it's not that uncommon:

> Although he has been popular, many feel the president lacks the dignity expected of the **office**.